# How to bind generic types with constraints

Tags: c#, generics, ninject

I'm using `Ninject` DI container. And I've got the two

```
public interface IRepository<T> where T : AbstractEntity<T>, IAggregateRoot
{ 
    // methods signatures
}

public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : AbstractEntity<T>, IAggregateRoot
{
    // implementations
}
```

Then I'm trying to bind them in a separate module

```
public class DataAccessModule : Ninject.Modules.NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        this.Bind<IRepository<>>().To<Repository<>>();
    }
}
```

where `this.Bind<IRepository<>>().To<Repository<>>();` is not recognized as a statement.

How do I make a bind?

Comment: possible duplicate of [NInject with Generic interface](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2216127/ninject-with-generic-interface)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Snagged this piece from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2425471/95573).  Looks like it worked for them:

```
Bind(typeof(IRepository<>)).To(typeof(Repository<>));
```