# Registering generic classes for generic interfaces with NInject

Tags: c#, generics, interface, ninject

I Have three generic interfaces

```
public interface IRepositorioBase<T> where T : class {    }
public interface IServiceBase<T> where T : class {}
public interface IAppBase<T> where T : class {}
```

for which I have three corresponding concrete generic class implementations

```
public class RepositorioBase<T> where T : class {    }
public class ServiceBase<T> where T : class {}
public class AppBase<T> where T : class {}
```

and the other class are create using the class generics, example

```
public class ExpenseCardRepository : RepositoryBase<ExpenseCard>, IExpenseCardRepository{ }

public class ExpenseCardService : ServiceBase<ExpenseCard>, IExpenseCardService
{
    private readonly IExpenseCardRepository _repository;

    public ExpenseCardService(IExpenseCardRepository repository) : base(repository)
    {
        _repository = repository;
    }
}

public class ExpenseCardApp : AppBase<ExpenseCard>, IExpenseCardApp
{
    private readonly IExpenseCardService _service;

    public ExpenseCardApp(IExpenseCardService service) : base(service)
    {
        _service = service;
    }
}
```

I would like a generic code only to bind all types of interfaces 
depending on the type of class it inherits

These is example [Ninject-Generic-Interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2216127/ninject-with-generic-interface) but I would like get of subclass.

Comment: Did you mean you are looking to register open generic types, as in the following hypothetical example that does not represent any Ninject syntax.
`Configure.Container(x => x.Register(typeof(IRepository<>), typeof(Repository<>));`

Comment: you're missing the definition of IExpenseCardRepository (here, in this example). Also the definition of `IExpenseCardApp`.

Comment: In my opinion, having specific interfaces for your repository such as `IExpenseCardRepository` is a design smell, violates SOLID and leads to maintainability issues. Take a look at [this article](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=92) where this is explained.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you're trying to achieve *can* only be done by creating an explicit binding for each type. After all `IExpenseCardRepository : IRepositoryBase<ExpenseCard>` is different from `ICustomerRepository : IRepositoryBase<Customer>`.
Now the good news is that you can automate this kind of work, by using  [Ninject.Extension.Convention](https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.conventions). If you stick to a naming convention, it can be done very easy. The naming convention is: Class name ends with the interface name (without a leading I of course). From your code it looks like you do. Then the solution is as easy as:

```
kernel.Bind(x => x.FromThisAssembly()
    .SelectAllClasses()
    .InheritedFrom(typeof(IServiceBase<>))
    .BindDefaultInterfaces());
```

This will bind `ExpenseCardService` to `IExpenseCardService` and `IServiceBase<ExpenseCard>`.

---

If you don't adhere to this naming convention, then things get a *little* more complicated: you'll have to provide (customize) the binding creation part yourself. What you would have to do is implement an [`IBindingGenerator`](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject.Extensions.Conventions/blob/master/src/Ninject.Extensions.Conventions/BindingGenerators/IBindingGenerator.cs) and use the `.BindWith<MyBindingGenerator>()` extension:

```
kernel.Bind(x => x.FromThisAssembly()
                  .SelectAllClasses()
                  .InheritedFrom(typeof(IRepositorioBase<>))
                  .BindWith<MyBindingGenerator>());
```

Your binding generator would then have to decide which types to bind *to* and create and return those bindings.

---

I have to give a word of caution, though: in most cases when i've seen this kind of design it was not necessary (there was a simpler solution available).
In general you should [favor composition over inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance).